# Android studio: Button onClick() not working

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclick

I have two buttons on my main Activity, which both should lead to another activity, but when I press my button, it doesn't change anything.

I have all three activities in my manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ModeratorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

Method for the two buttons in my main activity:

```
private void setUserTypeOnButtonClick(){
    Button userButton = findViewById(R.id.button_user);
    Button moderatorButton = findViewById(R.id.button_moderator);

    userButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            System.out.println("Clicked userbutton");
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), UserActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });


    moderatorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            System.out.println("Clicked moderatorbutton");
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), ModeratorActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the problem here? Did I leave something out?

Comment: share your whole activity code and xml layout with question

Comment: what is error comming?

Comment: Where are you calling this `setUserTypeOnButtonClick()` method?

Comment: Call setUserTypeOnButtonClick method in onCreate

Comment: @Iaalto I hate my life.

Comment: @squeezyPig just call setUserTypeOnButtonClick(); method in onCreateView

Comment: (Aside: we prefer answer material to exclusively appear in the answer space below, rather than as title/question updates. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the `setUserTypeOnButtonClick()` method after `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

The `setContentView()` does make the buttons visible but there is no click listener binding taking place, and hence the buttons don't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit :** Solution is just to
call `setUserTypeOnButtonClick()` inside `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Created activity_main");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUserTypeOnButtonClick();
}
```

Comment: but the moderator button is for the moderator activity and the user button is for the user activity?

Comment: @squeezyPig You just forgot to call your **`setUserTypeOnButtonClick()`** inside your `OnCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

you just call the   `setUserTypeOnButtonClick()` in your `onCreate` method

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot call the `setUserTypeOnButtonClick()` method in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

- You forget to call the method getUserTypeOnButtonClick().
- ToggleButton cannot cast to Button.
- And also ModeratorActivity and UserActivity OnBackPressed just call finish().